# Get sum of columns from a dataframe including map column - PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, sum

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like this, I have a map datatype column `Map<Str,Int>`

```
Date              Item (Map<Str,int>)                           Total Items      ColA

2021-02-01    Item_A -> 3, Item_B -> 10, Item_C -> 2                 15            10
2021-02-02    Item_A -> 1, Item_D -> 5, Item_E ->  7                 13            20
2021-02-03    Item_A -> 8, Item_E -> 3, Item_C ->  1                 12            30
```

I want to sum of all the columns including the map column. For map column the sum should be calculated based on keys.

I want something like this:

```
[[Item_A -> 12, Item_B -> 10, Item_C -> 3, Item_D -> 5, Item_E -> 10], 40, 60]
```

Not necessarily a list of lists, but I want the sum of the columns.

My approach:

```py
df.rdd.map(lambda x: (1,x[1])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).collect()[0][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregations for map column and for other columns separately, as you would need an `explode` on Items column, and then other columns which you need to sum would become hard to deal with.

Example dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2021-02-01', {'Item_A': 3, 'Item_B': 10, 'Item_C': 2}, 15, 10),
     ('2021-02-02', {'Item_A': 1, 'Item_D': 5, 'Item_E': 7}, 13, 20),
     ('2021-02-03', {'Item_A': 8, 'Item_E': 3, 'Item_C': 1}, 12, 30)],
    ['Date', 'Item', 'Total Items', 'ColA'])
df.show(truncate=0)
# +----------+----------------------------------------+-----------+----+
# |Date      |Item                                    |Total Items|ColA|
# +----------+----------------------------------------+-----------+----+
# |2021-02-01|{Item_C -> 2, Item_B -> 10, Item_A -> 3}|15         |10  |
# |2021-02-02|{Item_E -> 7, Item_D -> 5, Item_A -> 1} |13         |20  |
# |2021-02-03|{Item_E -> 3, Item_C -> 1, Item_A -> 8} |12         |30  |
# +----------+----------------------------------------+-----------+----+
```

Script:

```py
aggs = df.agg(F.sum('Total Items'), F.sum('ColA')).head()

df = (df
    .select('*', F.explode('Item'))
    .groupBy('key')
    .agg(F.sum('value').alias('value'))
    .select(
        F.map_from_entries(F.collect_set(F.struct('key', 'value'))).alias('Item'),
        F.lit(aggs[0]).alias('Total Items'),
        F.lit(aggs[1]).alias('ColA'),
    )
)
df.show(truncate=0)
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----+
# |Item                                                                |Total Items|ColA|
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----+
# |{Item_C -> 3, Item_E -> 10, Item_A -> 12, Item_B -> 10, Item_D -> 5}|40         |60  |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----+
```